# render of a white object is gray?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, color

I have got a interesting effect while rendering a white coffee mug.
[image: rendered mug]

[image: cycles material nodes]

When I render this white mug it appears more grey than white. I have a glossy ~10% and a defuse ~90% shader on this. Both shaders have the color set to white. But those pictures do not look as it should, do they? They are more grey than white.

More pictures and the blend on [google drive](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0Bz1YaRaP4qnDZDJ3Z0hXRmpJLW8).

Comment: Increase the value for your lights. Note that your cup is as tall as a 3 story building. In cycles, lights work as they would in real life, so to illuminate such a monumental object you need a very bright light.

Comment: That particular "tutorial" that you are following uses very large objects, but it does not address the intensity for the lights... this gets asked quite frequently... Maybe @AndrewPrice can make a correction for it...

Comment: Ok I added a sun with the strenght of about 40.000, this should be enough, shouldnt it? But it did not work, even if its more white than grey now.

Comment: This worked out well! Thank you for your help! :3 Here is a link to my image now https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bz1YaRaP4qnDdUZoMEJQRkZBUm8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The color of your cup depends on the color of the background, how much light you have in your scene, and the amount of objects you have in your scene. If you add a lamp or an object emitting light and set the value to at least 5, you will get a white mug

Comment: Ok I had already added a sun and it did not quite change the situation. Its strength is 5.300 and that should mean I am ok, doesnt it? I have tried putting the sun a bit closer to the mug, but it did not change a lot.

Comment: @Booming try making a plane emit light

Comment: @YusanMac205 it worked well out. Thank you! Here is my first render (I also made my cup smaller) https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bz1YaRaP4qnDdUZoMEJQRkZBUm8 thank you for your help!